# Apply hotkeys only while AltTab-ing in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to swap AltTab hotkey in Windows 11 for the hotkey Win+Tab. Additionally, I want to map Win+[Arrows] to work for navigating between the windows in the Task Switcher.

This is achieved with the snippet below:

```
LWin & Tab:: AltTab

LWin & Right:: AltTab
LWin & Left:: ShiftAltTab
```

However, this triggers the Alt Tab functionality even when trying to organize windows. For example, when typing Win+Left I'd want to send the active window to the left side of the screen.

So the question is: **How do I preserve the Win+[Arrow] functionality when I am not alt-tabbing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
; LWin + Tab = AltTab
<#Tab::
    Send, {Alt Down}{Tab}
    KeyWait, LWin ; waits for LWin to be relesead
    Send, {Alt Up}
return

; LWin + LShift + Tab = ShiftAltTab
<#<+Tab::
    Send, {Alt Down}{Shift Down}{Tab}
    KeyWait, LWin
    KeyWait, LShift
    Send, {Alt Up}
return

#IfWinActive Task Switching

    *Right:: Send {Right}
    *Left:: Send {Left}

#IfWinActive
```

**[Wildcard (*)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard)**: Fires the hotkey even if extra modifiers are being held down

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had to update the script to use the AltTab and ShiftAltTab keywords instead as it was having some side effects. Submitted and edit and as soon as it is accepted that represents what worked for me!

Comment: Could it be that those side effects are there because you have custom combinations with LWin as prefix key in your script? [Custom combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm#combo) says: "**For combinations with standard modifier keys, it is usually better to use the standard syntax**. For example, use `<+s::` rather than `LShift & s::`".

Comment: This is what I used #IfWinActive Task Switching

    *Right:: AltTab
    *Left:: ShiftAltTab
    *Up::^Up
    *Down::^Down

#IfWinActive

Comment: With this at the top of the script: LWin & Tab:: AltTab

Comment: So now, besides right&left working, while tab switching, up and down works as well. And there is no interference with keys. The only thing that missing is Win+Shift+Tab which reverses the cycle, but I prefer using the right arrow, that's why I didn't even want to fix that.

Comment: To go forwards (AltTab-ing) press Right, to go backwards (ShiftAltTab-ing) press Left in the above code. To use Win+Shift+Tab for ShiftAltTab-ing try the edited answer. What does *Up::^Up in this context?

Comment: You can move vertically and horizontally as well

Comment: I added it as another answer, as the comments here are limited

Answer (score 1):

With @user3419279's suggestion I got to this final solution:

```
LWin & Tab:: AltTab

#IfWinActive Task Switching

    *Right:: AltTab
    *Left:: ShiftAltTab
    *Up::^Up
    *Down::^Down

#IfWinActive
```

This allows me to move vertically and horizontally alongside many windows

[image]